# Call javascript var inside other script

Tags: javascript, var

I have this code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var rndn = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myexample.com/call=cid&rnd=7676786"></script>
```

I need to recall the "rndn" var to replace the number **7676786** in the second script.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rndn = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
var myScript = document.createElement('script');

myScript.setAttribute('src','http://myexample.com/call=cid&rnd='+rnd);

document.head.appendChild(myScript);
</script>
```

Comment: I like it, but why not simply add a new 'src' attribute to an existing script node? Check my answer to understand what I am saying

Comment: @Pradeep I would go for this method **if** the script tag only needed to be created once but if the OP want's to change the url parameter for whatever reason I would give the script tag an `id`, check if the element exists, if so update it, if not then create it.

Comment: @NewToJS this is just a demo, OP can customize it to his/her requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript:'http://myexample.com/call=cid&rnd='+rndn"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
<script id="other_script" type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rndn = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);

document.getElementById("other_script").setAttribute("src","http://myexample.com/call=cid&rnd="+rndn);
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("other_script")` will be `null`, and why the jQuery part?

Comment: This should be placed in - `window.onload=function(){//Here}` otherwise the javascript will run before the browser knows `other_script` exists or it could be placed in another function and have `window.onload=MyFunc;` to call it when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @NewToJS Not necessarily. Just swap the script blocks.

Comment: I understood, so I changed the order.

Comment: @Andreas You can just swap the script tags but the point is the original answer wouldn't work. I was offering a way of fixing the answer.

Comment: @NewToJS The browser "knows" the element as soon as the parser hits it in the markup

Comment: @Andreas So why swap the order of the script tags? Now you're contradicting yourself. The original answer luigonsec posted would return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null` in the console hence me offering a solution to fix the answer. The browser has to read the elements before you can attempt to change them.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the best way to do this is:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var rndn = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000);
document.write('<scri'+'pt language=\"Javascript\" src=\"http://myexample.com/call=cid&rnd='+rndn+'"></scri'+'pt>');
</script>
```

Comment: @NewToJS There's absolutely no problem with `document.write()` as long as it is used before the page has finished loading.